# Choppy transition: transform scalling animation on Safari

Tags: css, webkit, css-animations, mobile-safari

I have hard time making scaling animation that is not choppy in Safari (mobile). By choppy I mean you can clearly see that it's not 60FPS fluid animation. I need to say that element is absolutely positioned so it should not affect layout, should it?

First thing that I tried is animating element by creating CSS animation with 2 keyframes, going from `transform: scale(0);` to `transform: scale(1);`. For the effect I want to achieve I also used `transform-origin: top right;`. I also tried to optimize it by setting `will-change: transform;` but it was choppy.

I scrapped it and reworked it so it uses `transition: transform`. So by default element has `transform: scale(0);`, when certain class attaches to it, it gets `transform: scale(1);` which transition is animating, but it is still choppy.

After some research I found out that you want to avoid animating properties that require browsers to recalculate layout. I found out [this site](https://csstriggers.com/align-content) which says that WebKit (which Safari is using as far as I know) pretty much recalculates layout for every property change. Is that true, and if it is how do you make 60FPS fluid animations on mobile Safari (on other platforms using Safari it's not that noticeable because they have much more resources to recalculate everything and it appears a bit smoother than on mobile)?

Comment: Good article about optimizing css animations and more. [here](https://www.sitepoint.com/check-css-animation-performance-with-the-browsers-dev-tools/). There is not much else you can do about it. Keep in mind that other actions that take place in the same time (other animations or js scripts) that work at the same time will lower overall performance and can cause said problem.

Comment: `transform: scale(x)` is already one of the cheapest to animate so your issue may be caused by other animations that are on your page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 things that you can try:

- avoid using scale(0). In some browsers this gives problems. scale(0.01) is almost the same, and will be better for the browser.
- Try to make the animation handled by the GPU instead of the CPU. this can be done with the following code

  from: {transform: scale(0.01) translateZ(1px);}

  to:   {transform: scale(1)    translateZ(1px);}

Comment: For some reason this seemed more fluid and better. One more thing that I found out is that custom easings can also make a difference. It can seem less choppy with different easings.

Answer (score 1):

In reference to [this article](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/InternetWeb/Conceptual/SafariVisualEffectsProgGuide/AnimatingCSSTransitions/AnimatingCSSTransitions.html) section `Animate Changes in CSS Properties`, you can animate with keyframes, but need use a percentage like this:

More examples in [w3s article](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp).

PD: if you add an example, i'll try to help you.

```js
function animateStart(){
  document.getElementById('ball').classList.add('bounce');
}

function animationPause(){
  document.getElementById('ball').style.webkitAnimationPlayState='paused';
}

function animationContinue(){
  document.getElementById('ball').style.webkitAnimationPlayState='running';
}
```

```css
@-webkit-keyframes bounce {
    0% {top: 100px; left: 1px; -webkit-animate-timing-function: ease-in;}
    25% {top: 150px; left: 76px; -webkit-animate-timing-function: ease-out;}
    50% {top: 100px; left: 151px -webkit-animate-timing-function: ease-in;}
    75% {top: 150px; left: 226px -webkit-animate-timing-function: ease-out;}
    100% {top:100px; left: 301px;}
    }
 
.bounce {
    -webkit-animation-name: bounce;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 2s;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -webkit-animation-direction: alternate;
    }
    
.ball-style {
    position:absolute; top: 100px; left: 10px;
    height:100px; width:100px; border-radius:50px;
    background:-webkit-radial-gradient(30% 30%, white, red 10%, black);;
}

.wall {
    position:absolute; left: 400px; top: 100px;
    height: 150px;
    background: black;
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="Animate alternative"
       onclick="document.getElementById('ball').classList.add('bounce');">
       
<input type="button" value="Animate" onclick="animateStart()">
<input type="button" value="Pause" onclick="animationPause()">
<input type="button" value="Continue" onclick="animationContinue()">

<div id="ball" class="ball-style"></div>
 
<div class="wall">&nbsp;</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this helps but are you using javascript to add a class and start the animation with the class change?
jQuery for example can cause long depth analysis in the dom when manipulating elements, this is likely to interfere with the performance you need for achieving the desired fps.